# Parsing Nested JSON for child values with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to parse through some JSON data for a investment database I use to manage stocks I invest in (Australian ASX). I was doing this through exports direct from ASX but they have recently put protection in place against data scraping as such need to utilise another source

Best source I have found is as follows. The URL below is

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/ETPMPM.AX?interval=1d&range=1d

(where ETPMPM is the stock ticker. Others are NDQ, PME, WOW to list a couple)

This provides data in JSON format however I feel it is not fully clean (I say this because online Json parsers indicate errors).

What I want is to get a few different variables but key ones are

```
chart->result->meta->regularMarketPrice
chart->result->indicators->quotes->open
chart->result->indicators->quotes->close
chart->result->indicators->quotes->volume
```

In the past with json I have been able to just go through the keys and find what I am after but I can't with this for some reason.

Here is a simplied version of the relevant section of my code currently which prints out the json to screen but I can't get it to pull any particular variable

```
import requests
import json

def fetch_yahoo_finance_data():
    headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
    url ="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/GGUS.AX?interval=1d&range=1d"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch data. Status Code{response.status_code}")
        return None

data = fetch_yahoo_finance_data() 

print(data)
#print((data['chart'][0]['result']['meta'])['currency'])    #This line errors.Tried to base it off a similar nested json example online
#Following splits Json onto 1 field per line (normally) but in this case does nothing
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This provides data in JSON format however I feel it is not fully clean.

I think it should be "clean", try something like the following:

```
from typing import Any
import requests


HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
  }


def fetch_stock_data(ticker: str, interval: str = '1d', range_: str = '1d') -> dict[str, Any]:
  """Fetches stock data for a given ticker from Yahoo Finance and extracts key variables.

  Args:
    ticker: The stock ticker symbol.
    interval: The interval for the stock data. Defaults to '1d'.
    range_: The range of the data to fetch. Defaults to '1d'.

  Returns:
    A dictionary containing the extracted `regularMarketPrice`, `open`, `close`, 
      and `volume` values.

  Raises:
    ValueError: If the data cannot be parsed correctly or the expected fields are 
      missing.
  """
  url = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{ticker}?interval={interval}&range={range_}'
  response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
  data = response.json()
  try:
      result = data['chart']['result'][0]
      meta = result['meta']
      indicators = result['indicators']['quote'][0]
      return {
          'regularMarketPrice': meta.get('regularMarketPrice'),
          'open': indicators.get('open', [None])[0],
          'close': indicators.get('close', [None])[0],
          'volume': indicators.get('volume', [None])[0]
      }
  except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError) as e:
      raise ValueError(f'Error parsing data for ticker {ticker}: {str(e)}') from e


def main() -> None:
  print(f'{fetch_stock_data("ETPMPM.AX") = }')
  print(f'{fetch_stock_data("GGUS.AX") = }')
  print(f'{fetch_stock_data("TSM") = }')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Output on 2024-02-10**:

```
fetch_stock_data("ETPMPM.AX") = {'regularMarketPrice': 0.0, 'open': 196.5, 'close': 194.5399932861328, 'volume': 176}
fetch_stock_data("GGUS.AX") = {'regularMarketPrice': 33.18, 'open': 33.09000015258789, 'close': 33.18000030517578, 'volume': 20245}
fetch_stock_data("TSM") = {'regularMarketPrice': 133.11, 'open': 134.5, 'close': 133.11000061035156, 'volume': 16976800}
```

***Note:** The ticker is `ETPMPM.AX` and not `ETPMPM`.*

Comment: Awesome that works. Is there a link someone could point me to that explains how to work out this part so I can adapt for some other sources

Comment: I am referring to the "try" as I have some other sources to update. In particular including explaining where the [0] goes and why to pull the regularMarketPrice it is once but to pull all the others it is twice (or 3 times if you include the last). I realise the last one is basically like the index as there is multiple values but not quiet following the logic of the one in the "result =" and "indicators =" line. Again thanks for your help @Sash just trying to get a understanding of it for future